# How to add data points from dataframe to polygon map of administrative regions of Slovakia?

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, polygon, ggmap

pardon me if it is a basic question, this is my first time to write here, so my thanks in advance.

I have exported a report from Google Analytics with columns Longitude, Latitude and Sessions and I want to add these data points to polygon map I have created in R for administrative regions of Slovakia.

This is what I have for now.

```
##Load the Raster Library
library(raster)

##Get the Province Shapefile for Slovakia
slovakia_level_1 <- getData('GADM', country='SVK', level=1)
slovakia_level_2 <- getData('GADM', country='SVK', level=2)

##Plot this shapefile
plot(slovakia_level_1)

library(ggmap)   ##load the ggmap package so we can access the crime data

## read our dataset with sessions from google analytics ( more on how to read excel files http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/reading-data-from-excel-files-xls-xlsx-into-r)

library(readxl) ## this is the dataframe from google analytics and i would like to plot these data to the slovakia administrtaive region map
lugera <- read_excel("Analytics 01. [Lugera.sk] - [Reporting View] - [Filtered Data] New Custom Report 20190101-20190627.xlsx")
```

But i really do not know how to move on. I went based on this article http://data-analytics.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/geo2.html but i have stuck when i needed to plot points.

This is a sample how the report from google analytics looks like:

```
Longitude Latitude Sessions
17.1077 48.1486 25963
0.0000  0.0000  13366
21.2611 48.7164 4732
18.7408 49.2194 3154
21.2393 49.0018 2597
18.0335 48.8849 2462
19.1462 48.7363 2121
17.5833 48.3709 1918
18.0764 48.3061 1278
14.4378 50.0755 1099
20.2954 49.0511 715
18.1571 47.9882 663
18.6245 48.7745 653
17.8272 48.5918 620
18.9190 49.0617 542
19.1371 48.5762 464
-6.2603 53.3498 369
18.1700 48.5589 369
20.5637 48.9453 325
-0.1278 51.5074 284
21.9184 48.7557 258
```

Can someone help me how to progress from here as I am struggling to figure it out how to plot those points on polygon map.

Is it also possible to create a heat map over particular regions as well, please?

I hope it was clear, but if not, please tell me, i will improve my question, this is my first time to ask.

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

I was trying to reproduce Jay`s answer and the first map with red dots works awesome! Thanks!

But in case of the heat map I am getting errors and cannot reproduce the same map as I am getting several erros.

Belowe is my code how it looks like and I am not sure where is the issue as I tried to name my dataframe as `ses` the same way as in jay`s answer.

```
##Load the Raster Library

library(raster)  # imports library(sp)
slovakia_level_1 <- getData('GADM', country='SVK', level=1)


##Plot
plot(slovakia_level_1)
points(coordinates(slovakia_level_2), pch=20, col="red")

#ses is my google analytics dataframe where all 3 columns Longitude, Latitude and Sessions are numeric

## it is imported excel file to r and stored as a dataframe

ses

spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=ses[1:2], data=ses[3], 
                               proj4string=CRS(proj4string(slovakia_level_2)))
ppl.sum <- aggregate(x=spdf["Sessions"], by=slovakia_level_2, FUN=sum)
spplot(ppl.sum, "Sessions", main="Sessions in Slovakia")
```

These are the errors I am getting

```
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=ses[1:2], data=ses[3], 
+                                proj4string=CRS(proj4string(slovakia_level_2)))
Error in proj4string(slovakia_level_2) : 
  object 'slovakia_level_2' not found
> ppl.sum <- aggregate(x=spdf["Sessions"], by=slovakia_level_2, FUN=sum)
Error in aggregate(x = spdf["Sessions"], by = slovakia_level_2, FUN = sum) : 
  object 'spdf' not found
> spplot(ppl.sum, "Sessions", main="Sessions in Slovakia")
Error in spplot(ppl.sum, "Sessions", main = "Sessions in Slovakia") : 
  object 'ppl.sum' not found
```

Please, take my huge thanks for being so helpful on my first question and I cannot express my respect to all people at StackOverflow.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there's a `coordinates()` function included in the `sp` package (imported from `raster`), with which we easily can add the `points` to the `plot`.

```
library(raster)  # imports library(sp)
slovakia_level_1 <- getData('GADM', country='SVK', level=1)
slovakia_level_2 <- getData('GADM', country='SVK', level=2)

##Plot
plot(slovakia_level_1)
points(coordinates(slovakia_level_2), pch=20, col="red")
```

[image]

To get a heatmap using your google analytics data (here `ses`) we can use `spplot()`, also included in `sp`. First we need to create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, which - according to [this post on gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153906) - we aggregate to match `ses$Sessions`points and polygons from `slovakia_level_2`.

```
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=ses[1:2], data=ses[3], 
                               proj4string=CRS(proj4string(slovakia_level_2)))
ppl.sum <- aggregate(x=spdf["Sessions"], by=slovakia_level_2, FUN=sum)
spplot(ppl.sum, "Sessions", main="Sessions in Slovakia")
```

### Result

[image]

#### Data

```
# your data from google analytics above
ses <- structure(list(Longitude = c(17.1077, 0, 21.2611, 18.7408, 21.2393, 
18.0335, 19.1462, 17.5833, 18.0764, 14.4378, 20.2954, 18.1571, 
18.6245, 17.8272, 18.919, 19.1371, -6.2603, 18.17, 20.5637, -0.1278, 
21.9184), Latitude = c(48.1486, 0, 48.7164, 49.2194, 49.0018, 
48.8849, 48.7363, 48.3709, 48.3061, 50.0755, 49.0511, 47.9882, 
48.7745, 48.5918, 49.0617, 48.5762, 53.3498, 48.5589, 48.9453, 
51.5074, 48.7557), Sessions = c(25963L, 13366L, 4732L, 3154L, 
2597L, 2462L, 2121L, 1918L, 1278L, 1099L, 715L, 663L, 653L, 620L, 
542L, 464L, 369L, 369L, 325L, 284L, 258L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: oh this is beautiful! I believe it is OK if i will accept this as the answer. This absolutely answer my question. Thank you very much! It works nicely. Have agreat day Jay

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be this (`slov_df` is your dataset):

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)

slov_reg <- fortify(slovakia_level_2)

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = slov_reg, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), col = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_point(data = slov_df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

Nice solution by jay.sf. If you like this let me provide another option:

```
sp_google <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=slov_df[1:2], data=slov_df[3], 
                                    proj4string=CRS(proj4string(slovakia_level_2)))


slovakia_level_2@data$Sessions <- over(slovakia_level_2, sp_google, fn = sum)$Sessions
slovakia_level_2@data$id <- row.names(slovakia_level_2@data)
slov_reg <- fortify(slovakia_level_2, region = "id")
slov_reg <- join(slov_reg, slovakia_level_2@data, by="id")


ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = slov_reg, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Sessions), col = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow",  high = "red", na.value = "lightgrey") +
  theme_bw()
```

It's a little bit more work, but in the end ggplot offers you a much wider range of customization options. It's a question of your preference.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for quick response, my huge respect. I have tried it, but in the last part of the code geom_point i have received this error Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale? is it due to type of the variable in my dataframe Longitude and latitude are character and should be numeric? Much thanks again and wishing great day

Comment: Hi, yes `latitude` and `longitude`have to be numeric.

Comment: oh and by the way: you have points in your `df`that lie way outside of slovakia. You should remove any coordinate with a negative sign.

Comment: I have tried to convert Longitude and latitude to numeric so my end code looks like this  `library(sp)
library(ggplot2)

lugera$Longitude <- as.numeric(gsub(".", "", lugera$Longitude, fixed = TRUE))
lugera$Latitude <- as.numeric(gsub(".", "", lugera$Latitude, fixed = TRUE))

slov_reg <- fortify(slovakia_level_1)

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = slov_reg, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), col = "black", fill = NA) +
  geom_point(data = lugera, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))` but now only points are on the plot and map with regions is missing. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Aha, so everything where are minuses should be removed? Pardon me to take your time. I think the answer is correct, just  I need to make it run.

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub(".", "", lugera$Longitude, fixed = TRUE)` - what are you doing here? `as.numeric()` should suffice. No need to remove the point.

Comment: Cool thank you very much! Working! Much thanks! In case of heatmap, no it is not per region, it is actually per cookie from google analytics so they are individual sessions accross slovakia so i wanted to somehow visualize the heatmap from where are people coming the most. I am really new in this geospatial analysis in r, but I believe that I need to create sessions per region or is it possible somehow automatically  group individual coordinates based on the region? I will mark this question as answered but any additional info about heatmap would be awesome. Much thanks

Comment: Check out `stat_density2d()` and `geom_density2d()` for nice heatmaps. To group individual coordinates per region you have to reverse geocode the coordinates for the region they are in.

Comment: Hi, also amazing answer but for some reason for all answer I cannot pass the first line of code, in this case for sp_google as i am getting this error ```Error in .Call("RGDAL_checkCRSArgs", uprojargs, PACKAGE = "rgdal") : 
  "RGDAL_checkCRSArgs" not available for .Call() for package "rgdal"``` do you know please what it is causing?

Comment: The problem seems to be with assigning the coordinate reference system. Try replacing `CRS(proj4string(slovakia_level_2))` with `CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")`

Comment: Guys much thanks! I made it work. It was that there were some conflicts between packages so I have totally restart the session and now it works as it supposed. I found actually answer here for the error that it can casue that packages are overwritten. https://remi-daigle.github.io/2017-CHONe-Data/dataviz.nb.html THANK YOU